# How to install closed source software from command line

Tags: command-line

If I want to install restricted (closed source) software like Steam in Ubuntu, I have to use Software Centre.

Is there anyway to install such software right from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to install Steam. Please look at the software’s documentation for help with installing other third party software.

Open the terminal and run:

```
wget http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/signature.gpg && sudo apt-key add signature.gpg
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam"
```

The first line downloads and adds the signing key to your keymanager and the second line adds the actual repository to your system. I'm on 13.04 but Steam's installer used `precise` on that line, so I wouldn't change it to `raring`. Finally, you can install Steam by running the command below, which will also update your list of software sources:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam
```